# How ears identify the center(sofa name "Do") of a piece of music

Tags: ear-training

As titled, say,

When humming along with a piece of music, you will probably sing with sofa names without knowing the key signature of it, like **Birthday** song: **556517, 556521, 5553176, 443121...**

My question is, why we could identify the sofa name "Do" after listening to a piece of music, event if just part of it or a few sentences

What is the secret behind our ear? How this system works?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean. We don't need to identify key to sing along, and what do you mean by center in this context? You could make your 5 be "Do" here if you want, or your 1.

Comment: @DoktorMayhem - Interesting, but I can't make it work with 5 being Do. Unless it's in Mixolydian mode..! I think if listeners didn't know where do was, not knowing what letter it was doesn't matter, music wouldn't make a lot of sense. We need do, or 'home' - it's pivotal to how a piece works, isn't it? I think most people would know when a piece has 'come to rest' - with general Western music. And there's do - even for those who don't understand tonic sofas!

Comment: @DoktorMayhem Of course, we could make 5 be "Do" here. But the singing seems a little bit NOT INTUITIVE (unnatural / hard). Making 5 as "Do",  the Birthday song would be like "112143,112165,1116432,b7b76454", which is not what we usually  do. And by "center", I mean a "suitable Do" singing with sofa names in a more comfortable way

Comment: Related: [How do I identify the keytone by listening to a set of chords or a phrase?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/75528).

Comment: Happy birthday can be also be defined by the length of the notes, while “der Mond ist aufegangen” is ambiguous: doredofami re do ... could as well be : solasoti la sol. Btw. The reason  “why” is not answered in the other question.

Comment: I disagree with this question closure as the referenced question, and answers, discus musical clues to the tonic, but this is a clearly a physiology questions. Maybe that puts it out of scope of the site, but whoever suggested the other question as a duplicate was not reading carefully...what's new though?